# Line border animation on hover

Tags: html, css

I havent seen this subtle effect before and was wondering if it is possible to do this border animation on hover in html5/css only. Are there other pretty hover animation effects you found?

https://gfycat.com/evilidlefalcon

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image if it's about CSS

Comment: FYI. StackOverflow is made just for answers and not discussion posts. eg. "Are there any other pretty hover animation effects you found?". You can see more info at [StackOverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using the ":hover"
example: elemnt:hover

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>cool animation</title>
    <style>
        .test1 {
            /* Just centering the text */
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            /* adding transition */
            transition: 0.6s all;
        }
        /* using the hover method */
        .test1:hover {
            /* here you can specify whatever you want */
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="test1">test</h2>
</body>
</html>
```